# inheritance, how to use a class inside the other which is defined below it

Tags: c++, inheritance, prototype

I am prototyping the Class ***`class FSM`*** in the beginning, then using it in another class ***`class Run`*** which inherits the function `excute()`  virtually from another class named ***`class operation`***. and should also inherit the static variable declared in The class  ***`class FSM`*** named 
`static vector<FSM_inside> myFSM`  and uses it. the compiler isn't happy with it!
 how to make resolve this ?
and thanks...

Code:

```
  class FSM;
 class Run :public operations, public FSM
 {
 public:
string name;
void virtual excute()
{
    /////////////HERE is the problem /////////////////////
        for (int y = 0; y < myFSM.size(); y++) // compiler can't see the var(myFSM)
    // inside the FSM class, how to solve this ?
                if(myFSM[y].name==name)
                    {
                            flag=true;
                            myFSM[y].startFSM();
                        }   
}
  };






 class FSM_inside : public  Variables, public virtual transition
{
public:
       void parse()
       {
           if (temp.find("run") != string::npos)
        {
            removespaces(temp);
            temp.substr(temp.find("run")+3);
            t1.first.instructionList.push_back(new Run()); // t1 is a temp. so don't worry about it.

         }
       }

       void startFSM()
         {
           }
};






class FSM  //This is working, compiler doesn't complain about the Class FSM
{
public :
    static vector<FSM_inside> myFSM; // no problem
   void parse() // parser function calls the parser function inside FSM_inside and so on for start
       {
        FSM_inside temp;
            temp.parse();
            myFSM.push_back(temp);
        }
    void start(string d)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < myFSM.size(); y++)
                if(myFSM[y].name==d)
                      myFSM[y].startFSM();
         }

};
```

Comment: try moving the definition of `FSM` before `Run`...

Comment: @Sga well the problem class FSM_inside has inside it a Run variable and use it . Which mean  i need FSM to be the below the class RUN in the hierarchy. as you see, Run only needs to access the vector no more!

Comment: I was guessing that forward declaration must mean something... Anyway: separate method implementations from class definitions and you'll be fine.

Comment: i don't get really what you mean .

Comment: create a `.h` file and a `.cpp` file; keep definitions in the `.h` file and move your code in the `.cpp` file and `#include "FSM.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Prototyping a class is not enough information to inherit from that class. Why don't you change the order of the class definitions? Put FSM first, followed by Run.

Comment: well the problem class FSM_inside has inside it a Run variable and use it . Which mean  i need FSM to be the below the class RUN in the hierarchy. as you see, Run only needs to access the vector no more!

Comment: You can use prototyping to put pointers to the prototyped class inside another class. Smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` will work, too. In places where you want to use that pointer to access members of the class, the compiler needs to know the whole class definition. In your case you may need to redesign your class hierarchy to avoid a circular dependence.